# JS Measure the word and take action

Tags: javascript, forms

How to write a script in Javascript, which will measure the number of characters from the input text field on the form and if it is less than 2 will display an alert when you try to send the form, and if it is more than or equal to 2, will send the form with click send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the submit button inside the form, consider doing the following:

```
<button onclick="checkValidity()">Submit</button>
```

And within `<script>` tags inside the body of the html add the following code:

```
function checkValidity(){
     var val = document.getElementById('inputfield').value; //I'm assuming the id of the input text field to be inputfield
    if(val.length<2) window.alert('too short');

}
```

Comment: This will work if you are checking against one text box. However, if you have an entire form to submit to some server, this is not the best way doing it.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of achieving this, including:

**1- Adding a `pattern` attribute to your `input` element:**

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern=".{2,}">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In this case, if the input is invalid, the form will not submit and display the browser's default error message.

The regular expression `.{2,}` matches all strings with length 2 or more.

**2 - Checking the length of the input value via Javascript, and taking action accordingly:**

```js
function validate() {
  var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
  if(text.length < 2) {
    //display an alert or whatever
    console.log("invalid");
    return false; //form will not submit
  }
  return true; //form will submit
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit = "return validate();">
  <input type="text" id="input">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Using this method, once the form's `submit` button is clicked, the function `validate()` will execute. If the function returns true, the form will submit. If it returns `false`, the form will not submit.

Method 1 is quicker, while method 2 is more customizable/flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way :
**HTML :**

```
    <form id="form1">
        <input id="input2" type="text" placeholder="your text here"></input>
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
```

**JS:**

```
 $('#form1').submit(function(event){
        if($('#input2').val().length < 2){
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('ur input text will be more than 1 character');
        }
    });
```

Don't forget to import jQuery library before the code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```